# Layered and modular toon shader using a master node to stack them all

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I was looking at videos from Lightning Boy Studio that show that they built a modular toon shader where you just have to plug node group instances in a master node to stack the shaders. The color and different lights just stack without mixing. Here is an example:

[image: example nodes]

Of course, this is a shader they are selling so I'm not trying to rip them off by recreating it entirely, but I wanted to make my custom toon shading system using the same technique of "stacking" shaders using a master node, and I don't understand how they could achieve such a thing.

I tried using a chain of MixRGBs but failed, and then noticed that the input/outputs of their building blocks were green so I tried with Mix Shader, but I can't get anywhere. I always end up with either completely erasing the previous one or merging both like 50/50 and not stacked on each other.

My guess would be that some transparency trick is used.
Any idea?